# maximize $\sum_{A\subseteq [q], A\neq \emptyset} \alpha_A \log(|A|)$ with nonlinear constraints

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $[q]:=\{1,2,3, \ldots,q\}$, where $q$ is a positive integer. Consider a vector $\underline{\alpha}=(\alpha_A)_{A\subseteq [q], A\neq \emptyset}$, where each $\alpha_A \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that such a vector $\underline{\alpha}$ has $2^q-1$ entries.

Given such an $\underline{\alpha}$, we define the following:

$$ OBJ(\underline{\alpha}):=\sum_{A\neq \emptyset} \alpha_A \log(|A|), \quad v(\underline{\alpha})=\sum_{A\neq \emptyset} \alpha_A, \quad E(\underline{\alpha})=\sum_{\{ \{A,B\}: A,B \subseteq [q], A\cap B=\emptyset \}} \alpha_A \alpha_B, $$

where the sum in the definition of $E(\underline{\alpha})$ is taken over all unordered pairs of disjoint subsets of $[q]$.

Define $FEAS(1/4)=\{\underline{\alpha}: \alpha_A \geq 0 \text{ for all nonempty A },\,  v(\underline{\alpha})=1, \, E(\underline{\alpha})\geq 1/4 \}$.

I believe that the following is true:
$$OPT(1/4):= \max_{\underline{\alpha} \in FEAS(1/4) } OBJ(\underline{\alpha})=\frac{\log(\lfloor q/2 \rfloor \cdot \lceil q/2 \rceil)}{2}.   $$

I know that it is true when $q$ is even (it was proven), but I want to show that it also holds for odd $q$. I have verified that this is true for $q=3,5,7,9$ using SageMath, but would like to prove it by hand for general odd $q$.

I think that this problem can be solved using the language of probability. It is natural to do so given that the sum $v(\underline{\alpha})=\sum \alpha_A=1$ in the set $FEAS(1/4)$.

Consider a random variable $X$ on $2^{q}\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ (the power set of $[q]$, excluding the empty set) such that $\mathbb{P}[X=A]=\alpha_A$, where $A \subseteq [q]$.

Note that $2\cdot E(\underline{\alpha})$ can be interpreted as the probability that from the sets in $2^{[q]}\setminus \{\emptyset\}$ one selects two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$. Since by definition of $FEAS(1/4)$, $2\cdot E(\underline{\alpha}) \geq 1/2$, we see that we are more likely to select two disjoint sets rather than two sets which have a nonempty intersection.

One can verify that the set $FEAS(1/4)$ is compact, so there exists some $\underline{\alpha}^*\in FEAS(1/4)$ for which $F(\underline{\alpha}^*)=\max_{\underline{\alpha} \in FEAS(1/4) } F(\underline{\alpha})$. I conjecture that this vector $\underline{\alpha}^*$ has exactly 2 nonzero entries $\alpha^*_{A_1}=1/2$ and $\alpha^*_{A_2}=1/2$, where $|A_1|=\lfloor q/2 \rfloor$, $|A_2|=\lceil q/2 \rceil$, $A_1\cap A_2 =\emptyset$, and $A_1\cup A_2=[q]$. That is, the sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ form a partition of the first $q$ positive integers and their sizes are as equal as possible.

If it is difficult to prove this for general odd $q$, how would I prove it for, say, $q=5$? I would like to avoid using Lagrange multipliers with so many variables.

Let $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0\leq \gamma \leq \frac{q-1}{2q}$. Then
$$OPT(\gamma)=\{\underline{\alpha}: \alpha_A \geq 0 \text{ for all nonempty A },\,  v(\underline{\alpha})=1, \, E(\underline{\alpha})\geq \gamma \}.$$

In the paper for which I provided the link above, Serguei Norine shows that $OPT(\gamma)\leq \log(q(1-2\gamma))$   , with equality holding if and only if $\gamma=\frac{r-1}{2r}$ for some positive integer $r$ dividing $q$. When $r=2$ we see that $\frac{r-1}{2r}=1/4$, so $OPT(1/4)=\log(q/2)$ if and only if $q$ is divisible by two.

Comment: so you know how to get $\frac{\log 2}{2}$, right?

Comment: also, i dont know how this problem isn't trivial. you have $7$ variables and some mild constraints on them. just use [KKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions), which is just lagrange multipliers that also handles inequality constraints.

Comment: @mathworker21, yes but Lagrange multipliers become a nightmare for odd values larger than 3. I would like to know how to handle those cases

Comment: you should reword your question. it very very very much seems like you're just asking about the case $2k+1 = 3$.

Comment: FWIW I agree with @mathworker21 (hi! happy thanksgiving!) esp. if you're giving away 500 bounty for it!  -- i.e. you may wanna reword this question to something like: Pls solve the general $k$ case and in particular prove or disprove the "almost equal partition is optimal" conjecture.  This will also resolve the $2k+1=3$ case.

Comment: Happy Thanksgiving everyone!! Okay, I will make the changes now.

Comment: @antkam happy thanksgiving :). you might find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566026/coin-weighing-to-find-k3-similar-weight-sets) interesting. I consider the person who asked the question to be the most impressive person on math stack exchange who somewhat frequently uses it.

Comment: @Sarah - happy thanksgiving to you too!  You wrote that the $q$ even case has been proved.  Can you link to the proof?  Maybe someone will be able to modify it for $q$ odd...

Comment: @antkam Thank you for the suggestion. I rewrote some things, included the link, and explained the general result in the paper which implies the $q$ even case.

Comment: @Sarah hi sarah. i am very busy but potentially willing to put in some time. can you tell me though, what answering your question would imply? not necessarily what it would imply, if it would have big implications? if so, then it's probably too hard to be answered quickly on MSE...

Comment: @mathworker21 it has big implications in a particular subfield of graph theory, namely the subfield involving maximizing the number of proper vertex-colorings among all graphs with a fixed number of vertices and edges. However, I think that the optimization problem on its own is interesting.

Comment: @mathworker21 At this point, I would be greatly appreciative of any suggestions on how to possibly solve this optimization problem. I have tried several ideas, but they were not conducive to anything.

Comment: @Sarah my point was that then it's probably a hard problem... it seems that others have thought about it as well.

Comment: @antkam The proof for even $q$ is a one-liner (concavity of $\log$) but to extract from it the required result for odd $q$ seems not easy (or it only seems so to me?)

Comment: @fedja I do not think that it is easy. I could not apply the same ideas for odd $q$. I have now resorted to solving this for specific values of $q$ like $q=5,7$, etc.

Comment: @Sarah I think I can do it for large enough $q$ though I still need to check some details. Would you be interested?

Comment: @fedja Absolutely!! Is there a way for us to communicate privately through Math StackExchange?

Comment: @Sarah Not sure about "through MSE" (we can set up a chat room but the last time I tried it there was no LaTeX support there), but if you want a private conversation, just leave your e-mail and I'll write to you. However, check the argument below first :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it for sufficiently large $q$. It is going to be somewhat long and boring but, I hope, somewhat illuminating as to what is going on here.

**Step 1:** If there is any counterexample, then there is a counterexample in which the number of sets with positive associated probabilities is the minimal possible. Now notice that such a minimal counterexample cannot contain $3$ sets with positive associated probabilities with pairwise non-empty intersections or two such intersecting sets of the same cardinality. Indeed, if $A,B,C$ are three pairwise intersecting sets, then (I prefer $p$ to $\alpha$ for probabilities) we can fix $p_A+p_B+p_C$ and $p_A\log |A|+p_B\log|B|+p_C\log|C|$ (two linear constraints allowing at least one-dimensional linear perturbation) and notice that the sum of products of probabilities of pairwise disjoint sets can be written as $ap_A+bp_B+cp_C+d$ where $a,b,c,d$ depend only on probabilities of other sets, i.e., we have another linear functional of $p_A,p_B,p_C$ whose value we can now increase or, at least, keep fixed when doing our linear perturbation all the way until one of the probabilities $p_A,p_B,p_C$ hits $0$. The same argument works for two intersecting sets $A,B$ of the same cardinality if one notices that fixing $p_A+p_B$ and $p_A\log|A|+p_B\log|B|$ is now one linear constraint rather than two.

**Step 2:** Let us recap the proof of the bound $\log(q/2)$. It doesn't use Step 1 but can be combined with it any time.  Assume that we have some sets $A_i$ with positive associated probabilities $p_i$. Define
$$
Q_i=\frac{|A_i|}{q};\quad P_i=\sum_{j:A_j\cap A_i\ne\varnothing}p_j.
$$
Then our conditions are $\sum_i p_i=1$, $\sum_i p_iP_i\le \frac 12$ and we want to show that $\sum_i p_i\log (2Q_i)\le 0$. We just use the elementary inequalities 
$$
\log(2Q_i)\le 2(\sqrt{2Q_i}-1)\le \frac {Q_i}{P_i}+2P_i-2.
$$
Now if we multiply by $p_i$, add up, and notice in addition to the given conditions that $\sum_i p_i\frac {Q_i}{P_i}\le 1$ (just because $\sum_i \frac{p_i}{P_i}\chi_{A_i}\le 1$ pointwise where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$), we get the desired inequality at once.

For large odd $q$ we would like to write the same inequality but with $\log (2Q_i)+\frac 12\log\frac 1{1-\delta^2}$ on the left hand side where $\delta=1/q$. The advantage now is that $2Q_i$ can take only the values $1\pm\delta,1\pm 3\delta,\dots$, so we can gain a bit. Let's see how much. Assume $2Q_i=1+m\delta$ where $m$ is $\pm 1$ or $\pm 3$ (since $\log X$ is a concave function of $\sqrt X$, the gain for $|m|\ge 3$ is at least as large as the gain for $|m|=3$). Then in the desired inequality 
$$
\log (2Q_i)+\frac 12\log\frac 1{1-\delta^2}\le 2(\sqrt{2Q_i}-1)
$$
we have the left hand side equal to $m\delta-\frac{m^2-1}2\delta^2+O(\delta^3)$ and the right hand side equal to $m\delta-\frac{m^2}4\delta^2+O(\delta^3)$. For $m=\pm 1$, we have not a gain, but the loss of $\frac 14\delta^2+O(\delta^3)$ (the amount by which the LHS
exceeds the RHS), but for $m=\pm 3$ we have already a gain of $\frac 74\delta^2+O(\delta^3)$, which is almost $7$ times larger. It means that if we have a counterexample, then 
$$
\sum_{i:2Q_i=1\pm\delta}p_i\ge \frac 78-\varepsilon(q)
$$
where $\varepsilon(q)\to 0$ as $q\to\infty$. Combined with Step 1, we see that in any minimal counterexample, we have at most 3 sets (at most one of cardinality $\frac{q+1}2$ and at most two of cardinality $\frac{q-1}2$) that dominate the whole family.

**Step 3:** In any counterexample we must have at least one set with $2Q_i=1-\delta$ and at least one set with $2Q_i=1+\delta$. Indeed, we do not really need the factor on the RHS in the inequality
$$
\log (2Q_i)+\frac 12\log\frac 1{1-\delta^2}\le 2(\sqrt{2Q_i}-1)
$$
 to be exactly $2$. Any inequality of the kind
 $$
\log (2Q_i)+\frac 12\log\frac 1{1-\delta^2}\le \beta(\sqrt{2Q_i}-1)
$$
with positive $\beta$ will work equally well. So if one of the test-points $1\pm\delta$ is actually missing, we can rotate the line a bit to pass it through the other, then necessarily present, point, for which we need to move the corresponding value by about $\frac 14\delta^2$.  This will move the values at $1\pm3\delta$ by about $\frac 34\delta^2$, which is safe because the leeway there is about $\frac 74\delta^2$ and the rest of the points also stay below the line by concavity. I leave the details to you.

Thus, in a minimal counterexample, we must have exactly one set of cardinality $\frac {q+1}2$ (let's call it $A$) and at least one set of cardinality $\frac{q-1}2$.

The rest is a boring casework. Let's start with easy cases.

Suppose that the complement of $A$ is not present (in the sense that the associated probability is $0$). Then we should have either one set $B$ of cardinality $\frac{q-1}2$ overlapping with $A$ or 2 such sets $B$ and $C$ with $B\cap C=\varnothing$. In any case, there cannot be any set $D$ of cardinality greater than $\frac{q+1}2$ in the family because then $A,B,D$ will form a triple of pairwise intersecting sets. Thus, it will suffice to show that $p_A\le\frac 12$. Assume the contrary. Then in the first subcase (single set $B$), we have $(p_A+p_B)^2\le \frac 12$, so $p_A+p_B\le\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$, which contradicts the inequality $p_A+p_B\ge \frac 78-\varepsilon(q)$ from Step 2 for large $q$. Assume now that we have two sets $B$ and $C$. Then the condition that the probability of choosing two intersecting sets is at most $\frac 12$ implies that $(p_A+p_B+p_C)^2-2p_Bp_C\le\frac 12$. However, if $p_A>\frac 12$, then $p_B+p_C\le \frac 12$, so $2p_Bp_C\le \frac 18$ and $p_A+p_B+p_C\le \sqrt{\frac 58}$, which is again short of $\frac 78-\varepsilon(q)$ for large $q$.

Thus the complement of $A$ (let's call it $B$) has to be present. Assume that there is one more set $C$ of cardinality $\frac{q-1}2$. Then that set has to intersect with $A$ and, again, no set $D$ can have cardinality greater than $\frac{q+1}2$. All sets other than $A,B,C$ must have cardinalities at most $\frac{q-3}2$. Let $\sigma$ be the sum of their probabilities. Since every set must intersect either $A$ or $B$ and we are interested only in the case $p_A>\frac 12$ in this setting, we have
$$
(p_A+p_C)^2+p_B^2+2p_B\sigma\le\frac 12.
$$
One can check (just comparing $\log$ with the linear function through the two points of interest) that we have the desired inequality if $p_A\le\frac 12+\sigma$. However, the inequality above rewrites as 
$$
\frac 12+2(p_A+p_C-\frac 12)^2-\sigma^2=(p_A+p_C)^2+(p_B+\sigma)^2-\sigma^2\le\frac 12
$$
(the first identity follows from $p_A+p_B+p_C+\sigma=1$), so we conclude that even $p_A+p_C\le\frac 12+\sigma$.

Thus we are left with the case when we have one set $A$ of cardinality $\frac{q+1}2$, its complement $B$ and some sets of other cardinalities. If there is no set of cardinality $\frac{q+3}2$ or higher, we can treat this case similarly to the one just considered. So, suppose that a set $C$ of high cardinality is present. Then it intersects $A$ and $B$ but no other set (otherwise we would get an intersecting triple). Thus, if $|C|=\frac{q+m}{2}$ with some $m\ge 3$, then all other sets have cardinalities $\le\frac{q-m}{2}$. Let again $\sigma$ be the sum of probabilities of sets other than $A,B,C$. By the same comparison of $\log$ with the linear function through 2 interesting points, we conclude that it would suffice to prove the inequality
$$
p_A-p_B\le 3(\sigma-p_C).
$$ 
The restriction is now
$$
p_A(p_A+p_C)+p_B(p_B+p_C)+p_C(p_A+p_B+p_C)+2\min(p_A,p_B)\sigma\le\frac 12.
$$
Let us denote $p=\max(p_A,p_B), q=\min(p_A,p_B), r=p_C$ for brevity. The restriction will rewrite as
$$
p(p+r)+q(q+r)+r(p+q+r)+2q\sigma\le\frac 12
$$
and we need to conclude that $p-q\le 3(\sigma-r)$. We also have the normalization $p+q+r+\sigma=1$. Let $p=s+t, q=s-t$. Then we can rewrite the restriction as
$$
2s^2+2t^2+r^2+4sr+2s\sigma-2t\sigma\le\frac 12
$$
or
$$
(s+\sigma)^2+(s+r)^2+2sr+t^2+(t-\sigma)^2-2\sigma^2\le \frac 12
$$
Since $(s+\sigma)+(s+r)=p+q+r+\sigma=1$, the sum of the first two squares is already at least $\frac 12$, so we conclude that $2sr-2\sigma^2\le 0$. Since $2s=p+q$ is at least almost $7/8$, we have $\sigma\le s$ and thus $\sigma\ge r$. Let $\sigma=r+u$, $u>0$. Then the sum of the first two squares in the last displayed formula is $\frac 12+\frac 12u^2$, so we get
$$
\frac 12u^2+2sr+2t^2-2t(r+u)-(r+u)^2\le 0
$$
i.e.,
$$
2sr+2t^2-2tr-2tu-r^2-2ru-\frac 12u^2\le 0
$$
and we want to prove that $u\ge \frac 23t$.

Assume that $u<\frac 23 t$. Then the LHS is at least
$$
\frac 49 t^2+2sr-\frac{10}3rt-r^2=\left(\frac 23 t-\frac 52 r\right)^2+2sr-\frac{29}{4} r^2
$$
so it remains to check that $2s>\frac{29}4 r$. However $2s$ is almost $\frac 78$
while $\frac{29}4r\le 4(2r)$ and $2r\le 2r+u=r+\sigma=1-2s$ is only about $\frac 18$ at most.

The careful analysis of the proof shows that it is enough to get $4/5$ instead of $7/8$. It looks like choosing the comparison line parallel to the line through the 2 interesting points instead of parallel to the tangent line at $1$ allows one to cover all $q\ge 5$ ($q=3$ is special anyway), but I haven't checked this carefully. Feel free to ask question if something is unclear.

Comment: I just started reading this. So far I got through Step 1. Before I go on to ask you a question, first of all, I want to really thank you for taking the time to think about this problem and for writing all of this out.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why the counterexample vector, call it $p$, cannot have, for example, three pairwise non-disjoint sets $A,B$, and $C$. We can rewrite the condition $E(p)=ap_A+bp_B+cp_c+d$, where $a,b,$ and $c$ depend solely on the probabilities of other sets in the support of the vector $p$, because we know that these sets are pairwise non-disjoint. However, the sets $A,B,C$ may not be disjoint from other sets in the support of $p$, so $d$ could also depend on $p_A, p_B,$ or $p_C$. Nonetheless, I fail to see why this would show that we cannot have three such sets. Could you explain?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the second half of the inequality you wrote in Step 2:

Comment: $$
\log(2Q_i)\le 2(\sqrt{2Q_i}-1)\le \frac {Q_iP_i}+2P_i-2.
$$ This is a typo. What did you mean in the second inequality?

Comment: @Sarah I corrected this and 3 other typos I found. Let me know if there are more. As to the other question, $E(p)$ does not contain products $p_Ap_B, p_Ap_C, p_Bp_C$ if $A,B,C$ are pairwise intersecting, so there are four sorts of terms: containing $p_A$, containing $p_B$, containing $p_C$ and containing neither of them. I just grouped them. So $d$ is free from $p_A,p_B,p_C$ by definition.

Comment: Thank you. Right, $a$, $b$, and $c$ do not contain the products $p_Ap_B$, $p_Ap_C$, and $p_Bp_C$, but how do you know that in $d$ you don't contain a product $p_Dp_A$, $p_Dp_B$, or $p_Dp_C$, where $D$ is some set that could be disjoint from $A$, $B$, or $C$. For example, if $q=5$, you could have $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$, $C=\{1,3\}$, and $D=\{4,5\}$. Maybe I am misunderstanding. I thought that $a=\sum_{S\cap A=\emptyset} p_S$, $b=\sum_{S\cap B=\emptyset} p_S$, $c=\sum_{S\cap C=\emptyset} p_S$, and $d=\sum_{D\neq A,B,C} p_D \left( \sum_{S\cap D=\emptyset} p_S\right)$.

Comment: @Sarah The product $p_Dp_A$ is a part the term $ap_A$, not of $d$, with $p_D$ being a part of $a$. You have correct definitions of $a,b,c$ but $d$ is simply $\sum_{\{D,S\}:D,S\notin\{A,B,C\};D\cap S=\varnothing}p_Dp_S$. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Got it! Very nice observation. I'm a slow reader (I read everything very carefully and in detail), and I'm up to the part where you let $2Q_i=1+m\delta$ where $m$ is $\pm 1$ or $\pm 3$. You consider the desired inequality 
$$
\log (2Q_i)+\frac 12\log\frac 1{1-\delta^2}\le 2(\sqrt{2Q_i}-1).
$$
You say that the left hand side is equal to $m\delta-\frac{m^2-1}2\delta^2+O(\delta^3)$ and the right hand side equal to $m\delta-\frac{m^2}4\delta^2+O(\delta^3)$. I have been trying to figure that out for the last hour hahaha. How did you get that?

Comment: I got lost at this part: It means that if we have a counterexample, then 
$$
\sum_{i:2Q_i=1\pm\delta}p_i\ge \frac 78-\varepsilon(q)
$$  How did you arrive to this conclusion?

Comment: @Sarah "I have been trying to figure that out for the last hour hahaha" Taylor expansion in $\delta$ near $\delta=0$. I hope I haven't made a mistake though I'm notoriously bad in algebra. What are you getting? The next one is easy: we have our inequalities with gains and losses: $LHS_i= RHS_i+v_i$ where our $v_i$ are gains (negative) or losses (positive). If we multiply by $p_i$ and add up, we will get what we want if $\sum_i p_iv_i\le 0$. Since each gain is 7 or more times greater than each loss, the ratio of the corresponding sums of probabilities in a counterexample should be the same.

Comment: Your Taylor expansion is correct. I hadn't thought about Taylor expansions for a while...Okay, I follow what you said up until the very last part of the last sentence: "the ratio of the corresponding sums of probabilities in a counterexample should be the same." When $m=\pm 1$ we want $\sum_i p_i\left(\frac{\delta^2}{4}  +O(\delta^3)\right) \leq 0$, and when $m=\pm 3$ we want $\sum_i p_i\left(\frac{7\delta^2}{4}+O(\delta^3) \right) \geq 0$. I still don't see why $\sum_{i:2Q_i=1\pm\delta}p_i\ge \frac 78-\varepsilon(q)$, since $m=\pm 1$ and $m=\pm 3$ correspond to different set sizes.

Comment: @Sarah You misinterpreted it. We want $\sum_{i:2Q_i=1\pm\delta}p_i(\frac{\delta^2}4+O(\delta^3))+\sum_{\rm{other }i}p_i(-\frac{7\delta^2}4+O(\delta^3))\le 0$. If it holds, we win, so we can lose (have a counterexample) only if $\sum_{i:2Q_i=1\pm\delta}p_i\ge [7+O(\delta)]\sum_{\rm{other\ \ }i}p_i$. Since the sum of all $p_i$ is $1$, the conclusion follows.

Comment: Understood, thank you. Now onto Step 3. You claim that in a minimal counterexample we must have at least one set with $2Q_i=1-\delta$ and at least one set with $2Q_i=1+\delta$. You say that "if one of the test-points $1\pm\delta$ is actually missing, we can rotate the line a bit to pass it through the other". What do you mean by "rotate the line"? Also, in the case where we assume that the complement of $A$, a set of size $\frac{q+1}{2}$, is not present and we have exactly one set $B$ of size $\frac{q-1}{2}$ that intersects with $A$, why does it suffice to show that $p_A\le\frac 12$?

Comment: @Sarah By "rotating the line" I mean changing $\beta$ in the inequality $\log(2Q_i)+\frac 12\log\frac 1{1-\delta^2}\le\beta(\sqrt{2Q_i}-1)$. As I said, $\beta=2$ (the tangent line at $2Q_i=1$) is of no particular importance in the argument and the claim is that if either $1+\delta$ or $1-\delta$ is missing, then we can choose $\beta$ so that the inequality holds for all remaining points and win. As to the second question, in that case all sets other than $A$ have cardinalities $\le \frac{q-1}2$, so the logarithmic sum is at most $p_A\log\frac{q+1}2+(1-p_A)\log\frac{q-1}2$.

Comment: I read the entire argument, such a wonderful case by case analysis. I am going to see if I can see how to get it for all odd $q\geq 5$. I was able to figure out the $q=3$ case by shifting weights among the 7 entries, but this method won't work for $q\geq 5$.

Comment: @Sarah Great. The point is to get at least $4/5$ instead of $7/8$ ($7/8$ is an overkill) and the main freedom is the careful choice of $\beta$ in the comparison. Let me know whether it works out.

Comment: I'm thinking about your most initial observation again. If $A,B,C$ are pairwise intersecting sets, then we can express the constraint $E(p)=ap_A+bp_B+cp_C+d$, where $a,b,c,d$ depend only on probabilities of other sets. You say that we can increase or, at least, keep fixed, the value of $E(p)$ when doing our linear perturbation all the way until one of the probabilities $p_A,p_B,p_C$ hits $0$. Maybe it isn't clear to me what you mean by "linear perturbation". Do you mean to shift all of the mass from $p_A,p_B, p_C$ to other entries? If so, how can we guarantee that $E(p)$ won't decrease?

Comment: @Sarah It is just the linear programming nonsense. Since you have 3 variables and two linear constraints, you can find a non-zero vector $(dp_A,dp_B,dp_C)$ such that $dp_A+dp_B+dp_C=0$ and $dp_A\log|A|+dp_B\log|B|+dp_C\log|C|=0$. Then $p_A(t)=p_A+tdp_A$, etc. have a fixed sum and a fixed logarithmic sum (other probabilities stay unchanged) and $E(p(t))$ is a linear function of $t$, so we can move $t$ in either positive or negative direction and not decrease $E(p(t))$. This movement is legitimate as long as $p_A(t),p_B(t),p_C(t)$ remain non-negative, so we stop when one of them hits $0$..

Comment: You definitely know much more about linear programming than I do! Do you have a suggestion for a nice source where I can read more about this? I think it would be very valuable to me to learn more about linear programming...

Comment: @Sarah Just google "linear programming" and you'll see a lot of hits from Wiki articles to lecture notes to books. I'm reluctant to recommend anything in particular because I have no idea of what your background is in general, so just choose an exposition that matches your level and is written in a language clear to you. Indeed, it is a useful thing to know. We had a short mini-course of it within the general course of "optimization methods" or something like that when I was a student. All you need to grasp the main ideas quickly is a decent knowledge of linear algebra.

Comment: Okay, I more or less see why such a vector $(dp_A, dp_B, dp_C)$ exists because we can write both of the constraints as equality constraints equaling zero (we can introduce a slack variable in the inequality constraint). However, I do not see why we can move $t$ in either the positive or negative direction and not decrease $E(p(t))$. I have been searching online like crazy to try to understand this.

Comment: @Sarah That is true about any linear function $L(t)$: it is either increasing all the way (in which case $L(t)\ge L(0)$ for all $t\ge 0$), or decreasing all the way (in which case $L(t)\ge L(0)$ for all $t\le 0$), or constant. Also I do not try to write inequality constraints as equality ones with a slack variable. I'm doing something much simpler. If a counterexample exists, it has certain values of $\sum_A p_A$  ($=1$), $\sum_A p_A\log|A|$ and $E(p)$. I now change it so that the first two stay the same and the third one goes up (so I still have a counterexample) but there is one less $p_A>0$

Comment: Okay, after some thought and reading up on basic linear programming, I understand why having more variables than linear constraints would imply you have such a non-zero vector $(dp_A, dp_B, dp_C)$. Now you consider $p_A(t)=p_A+tdp_A$, $p_B(t)=p_B+tdp_B$, $p_C(t)=p_C+tdp_C$ with a fixed sum and fixed logarithmic sum, where all of the other probabilities remain unchanged. Now $E(p(t))$ is linear with respect to $t$, and it is either increasing/decreasing, which means that we can either decrease or increase $t$ while still maintaining that $E(p(t))\geq E(p)\geq 1/4$.

Comment: Okay, all of what I said in the previous comment is understood, but I still have some inquiries. The $p_A(t), p_B(t),$ and $p_C(t)$ are all linear, but how can we guarantee that we can get at least one of them to become zero while still maintaining that $E(p(t))\geq E(p)$? For example, say we manage to move $t$ so that $p_A(t)=0$. Then $t=-p_A/dp_A$. How do we know that $E(p(-p_A/dp_A))\geq E(p(0))=E(p)$? Also, how does getting one of $p_A(t), p_B(t),$ or $p_C(t)$ to become zero show that we can consider one less $p_A>0$? Sorry for all of the questions, I just really want to understand.

Comment: @Sarah It goes the other way around. We choose the direction to which to move $t$ from the condition that $E(p(t))$ should not decrease and try to go as far as we can. Note that since $dp_A+dp_B+dp_C=0$, at least one of $dp_A,dp_B,dp_C$ is positive and at least one is negative, so we cannot go too far: sooner or later one of the probabilities will hit $0$ but we have no idea which one it is going to be at that moment. The second phrase was just awkward. It should read "the number of of sets with associated positive probabilities will go down by at least one" (the one that hit $0$).

Comment: I am trying to understans the point of introducing $t$. I understand that it allows us to treat $E(p(t))$ as a linear function of $t$. More specifically I am trying to understand the purpose of $p_A(t), p_B(t)$, $p_C(t)$. We can get at least one of them to go to zero, but I still do not understand how this leads us to see how we can't have three sets with pairwise intersecting probabilities. We have shown that one of $p_A(t), p_B(t)$, $p_C(t)$ is zero, not one of $p_A, p_B, p_C$. Could you explain this?

Comment: @Sarah If we had a minimal counterexample with $p_A,p_B,p_C>0$ and $A,B,C$ pairwise intersecting, then we could create a new one replacing them by $p_A(t),p_B(t),p_C(t)$ respectively in which we would have even fewer sets with associated positive probabilities, thus contradicting the minimality assumption. Hence, such $A,B,C$ could not exist in the first place. Of course, this logic applies only to the *minimal* counterexample but if we have any counterexamples at all, we should have a minimal one among them. Sorry for my poor ability to explain things clearly enough. :-)

Comment: @Sarah We do because $p_A(t)+p_B(t)+p_C(t)=p_A+p_B+p_C$ for all $t$ (that was the whole point of the condition $dP_A+dp_B+dp_C=0$).

Comment: Yes, I quickly deleted that last comment because I remembered again soon after! Okay, I finally got it! This is very cool!!! Thank you so much for explaining this.

Comment: I am thinking again about why the inequality $\sum_i p_i\frac {Q_i}{P_i}\le 1$ holds. You said it is because $\sum_i \frac{p_i}{P_i}\chi_{A_i}\le 1$ pointwise, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of the set $A$. I am probably thinking about this the wrong way, but is it true that $\sum_i \frac{p_i}{P_i}\leq \sum_i p_i$? It isn't necessarily true that $\frac{p_i}{P_i}\leq p_i$, so I am not sure...

Comment: @Sarah No, the reason is completely different. Take any point $x\in\{1,\dots,q\}$. Notice that for all sets $A$ with $x\in A$, we have $P_A=\sum_{B:A\cap B\ne\varnothing}p_B\ge \sum_{B:x\in B}p_B=:P$, so $\sum_A \frac{p_A}{P_A}\chi_A(x)=\sum_{A:x\in A}\frac{p_A}{P_A}\le \sum_{A:x\in A}\frac{p_A}{P}=1$.

Comment: I have been thinking a lot about what you said at the end of your analysis: "It looks like choosing the comparison line parallel to the line through the 2 interesting points instead of parallel to the tangent line at 1 allows one to cover all $q\geq 5$". I know that you said that you haven't checked this carefully. I am trying to understand what exactly you meant. For example, with $q=5$: It is not possible to find a $\beta$ such that $\log(1+m/5)+\log\left( \frac{1}{1-(1/5)^2}\right) \leq \beta (\sqrt{1+m/5}-1)$ for both $m=1,-1$.

Comment: I understand that we can choose $\beta$ so that the inequality holds for, say, $m=1$, and all other $1\pm m/5$ for other $m\geq 3$. What bothers me about the argument for general $q$ is the inequality $\sum_{|A|=1\pm \delta} p_A \geq 7/8-\epsilon(q)$, where $\epsilon(q)\to 0$ as $q\to \infty$. I would love to obtain a result for sufficiently large $q$, but it will not be possible like this. Hmm, I will try to see what I can do with specific values of $q$, starting with $q=5$. If something comes of it, I will message you via chat on MSE.

Comment: @Sarah You cannot have it nice and clean. You'll have some loss for $m=\pm 1$ but the goal is to get at least $4$ times larger gain for $m=\pm 3$ and larger. For sufficiently large $q$ we can gain almost $7$ times as much as we lose but that is an overkill. If you have trouble figuring it out, I can try to look into it but not immediately: have some other fish to fry right away...

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, but another concern has arisen. Your observation that a minimal counterexample $p$ cannot have three pairwise intersecting sets is crucial. You prove it by contradiction by showing that in the end we can find another vector, call it $p(t)$, with smaller support. However, this vector may not be in the set $FEAS(1/4)$ because it may have negative entries. The definition of $FEAS(1/4)$ requires that the entries be nonnegative. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @Sarah It *cannot* have negative entries because we stop as soon as one entry hits zero (the first one that stops being positive).

Comment: Sorry, I am going over everything again because I am working on solving the $q=5$ case. I completely understand why $\sum_A \frac{Q_A}{P_A}p_A\leq 1$, as you previously explained. Why it is true that $\sum_A \frac{Q_A}{P_A}p_A \leq \sum_A \frac{\chi_A}{P_A}p_A$? Sure, $Q_A\leq 1$, but $\chi_A(x)=1$ only if $x \in A$.

Comment: @Sarah Of course what you wrote is not true. To get the inequality for $Q$'s from the inequality for $\chi_A$'s you need to sum over $x\in\{1,\dots,q\}$

Comment: Yes, of course I thought about that. Then that means $$\sum_{x\in [q]} \sum_{A:x\in A} \frac{Q_A}{P_A}p_A\leq \sum_{x\in [q]}  \sum_{A:x\in A} \frac{\chi_A(x)}{P_A}p_A\leq \sum_{x\in [q]}  1 =q,$$ right? How does this imply that $\sum_A   \frac{Q_A}{P_A}p_A\leq 1$?

Comment: @Sarah $Q_A$ is the cardinality of $A$ *divided by* $q$, not just the sheer cardinality!!! Looks like you are just a bit tired today :-)

Comment: No, I am just stupid,but I want to understand. I know that $Q_A:=|A|/q$. So rewrite the inequalities as $$\sum_{x\in [q]} \sum_{A: x \in A} \frac{|A|}{qP_A} p_A \leq \sum_{x\in [q]} \sum_{A: x \in A} \frac{\chi_A(x)}{P_A} p_A \leq \sum_{x\in [q]} 1 =q.$$ I still do not see how this means that $\sum_A \frac{|A|}{qP_A} p_A\leq 1$. What I see is that $$\sum_{x\in [q]} \sum_{A: x \in A} \frac{|A|}{qP_A} p_A=\sum_A \frac{|A|^2}{qP_A} p_A,$$ because the number of times the term $\frac{|A|}{qP_A} p_A$ appears in the sum above is $|A|$. I still don't see how $\sum_A \frac{|A|}{qP_A}p_A \leq 1$.

Comment: I do not see it because then by what I said in my previous comment, $$\sum_A \frac{|A|^2}{q^2P_A}p_A\leq 1,$$ so $$\sqrt{\sum_A \frac{|A|^2}{q^2P_A}p_A}\leq 1,$$ but this won't give us what we want. I have been mulling over this for a while. I just don't think in the right direction, I guess.

Comment: @Sarah Tired you are :-) We have $\sum_Ap_A\frac{\chi_A(x)}{P_A}\le 1$ for all $x$. Now summing over $x$ and taking into account that $\sum_x\chi_A(x)=|A|$ for all $A$, we get $\sum_A p_A\frac{|A|}{P_A}\le q$, which, after dividing by $q$, gives the desired inequality. Get some rest and look at everything with fresh eyes in the morning ;-)

Comment: You were right, I was tired that day (I had only gotten 4 hrs of sleep the night before). I completely understood why the inequality holds. Now I am thinking about the most difficult case: When we have the set $A$ of size $\frac{q+1}{2}$, its complement $B$, and some sets of other cardinalities. Suppose that we have some set $C$ of size $\frac{q+m}{2}$, where $m \geq 3$. $C$ can only intersect $A$ and $B$, but no other sets, else we'd have an intersecting triple. You claim that it suffices to show that $$p_A-p_B\leq 3(\sigma-p_C),$$ where $\sigma:=\sum_{S:|S|\leq \frac{q-3}{2}} p_S$.

Comment: I have been trying to see for the last 3 days why it suffices to show the inequality above. We can rewrite it as $$p_A\leq 3\sigma-3p_C+p_B.$$ Then $$OBJ(p)\leq \log\left(\frac{q-3}{2} \right)\sigma+\log\left(\frac{q-1}{2} \right)p_B+\log\left(\frac{q+1}{2} \right)p_A+\log(q)p_C $$ $$\leq \log\left(\frac{(q-3)(q+1)^3}{2^4} \right)\sigma+\log\left(\frac{q^2-1}{4} \right)p_B+\log\left(\frac{8q}{(q+1)^3} \right)p_C, $$ but I don't see how to obtain that this is less than or equal to $(1/2)\log\left(\frac{q^2-1}{4} \right)$. As usual, I am probably thinking in the wrong direction...

Comment: By the way, I have a proof (using your ideas) that $OPT(p)=\log(6)/2$ for $q=5$. I actually got that $\sum_{S:|S|=2,3} p_S\geq 0.768929$, so since this is smaller than $4/5$, I had no choice but to take a different route in some cases. However, some cases were easier simply due to the fact that for $q=5$, sets of size less than $\frac{q-3}{2}$ are all of size $1$ and they contribute nothing to $OBJ(p)$. For $q\geq 7$ I managed to get $\sum_{S:|S|=\frac{q-1}{2},\frac{q+1}{2}} p_S\geq 4/5$. I'm just having trouble with that very last case I mentioned before.

Comment: There is one other obstacle now that I face: To determine the feasible vector $p$ which gives us $OBJ(p)=OPT(1/4)$. I feel like this could possibly be hidden in your proof because it seems like we are narrowing down to having precisely two sets in the support of $p$, namely a set $A$ of size $\frac{q-1}{2}$ and its complement. The issue is that this argument is based on the assumption that sets of these sizes "dominate" the support of $p$ (this came from the contradiction approach). How can we determine the structure of the vector from this proof? Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Sarah For the first question, forget about logarithm altogether and just replace it by the linear function $L$ having the same values at $\frac{q\pm 1}{2}$ and state and prove the desired inequality for $L$; it is much easier. The second question is harder because we can say that the optimal vector must turn into the two-component vector after our first reduction and all operations should be "neutral" (i.e., all corresponding linear functions should be constant), bu still some extra argument is needed to show that it was that vector from the beginning. Let's think of it later, however.

Comment: I am having a little trouble understanding what you mean by "the linear function $L$ having the same values at $\frac{q\pm 1}{2}$". Do you mean a linear function $L$ taking in values of the form $\frac{q\pm m}{2}$? Sorry, could you explain? Thank you again for being patient with me. You're wonderful :-)

Comment: @Sarah The unique linear function $L(x)=\beta x+\gamma$ such that $L(x)=\log(x)$ for $x=\frac{q\pm 1}{2}$. Note that $\log x\le L(x)$ for all integers and $L(q/2)$ is exactly the bound we want to obtain.

Comment: I think I never quite understood this line you talk about in your analysis. The equation I got is $$L(x)=\log \left( \frac{q+1}{q-1} \right)x+\left( \frac{q+1}{2} \right)-\left( \frac{q+1}{q-1} \right) \left( \frac{q+1}{2} \right), $$ and yes, I see that $L(q/2)$ equals the bound we want. I also see that $\log(x)\leq L(x)$ for all integers $x$. What I do not see is how to relate this line to $OBJ(p)$. Okay, you said to forget about $OBJ(p)$, and perhaps this is why I am confused. I still don't see how showing $p_A-p_B\leq 3(\sigma-p_C)$ suffices for the last case. Could you explain?

Comment: @Sarah We have $\sum_{D}p_D\log|D|\le\sum_D p_DL(|D|)\le p_AL(\frac{q+1}{2})+p_BL(\frac{q-1}{2})+p_C L(\frac{q+m}{2})+\sigma L(\frac{q-m}{2})$ with some $m\ge 3$. Now just ask yourself when the last expression is at most $L(q/2)$. You can figure it out just knowing that $L$ is an increasing linear function. What do you get?

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out. Since $L$ is linear, the right side of the inequality you wrote ends up being $$L(q/2)+(p_A-p_B)L(1/2)+(p_c-\sigma)L(m/2).$$ Since we want this to be at most $L(q/2)$ we end up with wanting $$(p_A-p_B)L(1/2)\leq (\sigma-p_c)L(m/2).$$ I still have not used the fact that $L$ is increasing, but I am not sure where to go from here to end up with $p_A-p_B\leq 3(\sigma-p_C)$. It seems that I am close, though...

Comment: @Sarah Almost there, indeed. Start it all over: write $L(x)=\beta x+\gamma$ and use the identity $p_A+p_B+p_C+\sigma=1$ to cancel $\gamma$. What is left?

Comment: Okay, so now I end up with $p_A-p_B \leq m(\sigma-p_C)$. I know that $m\geq 3$, but I how do I know that I can bound this above by $3(\sigma-p_C)$? It is probably obvious and I am just not seeing it haha.

Comment: I can write the bound $m(\sigma-p_C)\leq 3(\sigma-p_C)$ if $\sigma-p_C\leq 0$, but what if this is not the case?

Comment: @Sarah Ah, but if you've read the proof, you've seen that we actually show $|p_A-p_B|\le 3(\sigma-p_C)$, so the RHS is positive (and it was a part of the argument). Also you should get more sleep again: we need to derive what is needed from what I claimed, not vice versa ;-)

Comment: I did read the proof, but it has been a while. Okay, I will go over it again carefully.

Comment: Hello, I hope that you are safe and well. I have been working on generalizing your argument for when $1-2\cdot E(\underline{\alpha})=\sum_{\{ (A,B): A,B \subseteq [q], A\cap B\neq \emptyset \}} \alpha_A \alpha_B \leq 1-2 \gamma$, where $1/4 - \epsilon \leq \gamma \leq 1/4$, for some $\epsilon >0$. I claim that $OPT(\gamma)=\frac{1}{2}\log \left( \frac{q^2-1}{4} \right) + \frac{\sqrt{1-4\gamma}}{2} \log\left( \frac{q+1}{q-1} \right)$ if $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small. I have been successful in proving this for $q=5$ using your observations/techniques. As for $q\geq 7$, I've managed to get

Comment: all of the cases, except the very last one! This is the case where you have a sets $A$ and $B=A^c$ in the support of the vector $\mathbf{p}$, where $|A|=\frac{q+1}{2}$, and there is also some set $C$ such that $|C|=\frac{q+m}{2}$, where $m \geq 3$. In order to prove my claim, it would suffice to show that $p_A-p_B\leq 3(\sigma-p_C)+\sqrt{1-4\gamma}$ (recall that $\sigma =\sum_{\{S:|S|<\frac{q-1}{2} \}} p_S$. However, I am having a LOT of trouble proving this. For $q=5$ I was able to obtain the maximum value via other methods, but $q\geq 7$ is more complicated. By the way, I am working with the

Comment: bound $\sum_{\{S:|S| =\frac{q-1}{2}, \frac{q+1}{2} \}} p_S\geq 4/5$. If you have ANY suggestions I would gladly take them. I am so close! I cannot thank you enough for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not an answer** but some thoughts.

It seems difficult to me to verify that OPT even for $q=5.$ What you have is, naively, a nonconvex optimization problem over $2^q-1$ variables. So without some extra insight it seems hopelessly difficult computationally.

Here is an idea for a stronger conjecture that can be verified as a nonconvex optimization in $q^2$ dimensions, more specifically testing copositivity of a $q^2\times q^2$ matrix. That's still very difficult computationally, but slightly better in theory.

Let $$\hat E(\underline\alpha)=\sum_{A,B\in 2^{[q]}\setminus\{\emptyset\}}\alpha_A\alpha_B\frac{|A\cap B|}{\min(|A|,|B|)}.$$

$\hat E(\underline\alpha)$ is a lower bound on $1-2E(\underline\alpha).$ Optimistically we might have
$$OBJ(\underline\alpha)\leq mq\hat E(\underline\alpha)+c\qquad(?)$$
where $m,c$ are the unique numbers satisfying $mx+c=\log x$ for $x\in \{\tfrac{q-1}2,\tfrac{q+1}2\}.$ This would imply your OPT by plugging in $\hat E(\underline\alpha)=\tfrac12.$

Homogenizing, we want
$$OBJ(\underline\alpha)v(\underline\alpha)\leq mq\hat E(\underline\alpha)+cv(\underline\alpha)^2\qquad(?)$$
for all vectors $\alpha$ with non-negative entries.

The functions $OBJ,v,\hat E$ are homogeneous linear, linear, and quadratic functions respectively of the $q^2$ numbers

$$p_{i,j}(\underline\alpha)=\sum_{\substack{|A|=i\\A\ni j}}\alpha_A/|A|$$

In particular

$$\hat E(\underline\alpha)=\sum_{i,j,k=1}^q\max(i,k)p_{i,j}(\underline\alpha)p_{k,j}(\underline\alpha).$$

So this reduces to a slightly easier problem computationally.